# Laravel local dev environment redirects to https instead of http

Tags: php, laravel, macos, https

I have a Laravel application in my local dev environment(Mac Big Sur). When I run my application using

```
php artisan serve
```

the application starts up. But then when I try to access it on

```
127.0.0.1:8000
```

it tries to load it on https instead of http.

I have tried the following but it does not work.

Added the following values in `.env` file

```
FORCE_HTTPS=false
```

Can someone help me on this.

Comment: Seems like this is a browser issue, suggest you to clear the cookies and cache from your browser and try again

Comment: Just check in the private window of the tab or any other browser. It may be the cache issue as well. Remove the cache of Laravel application by running "php artisan optimize:clear" command

Comment: Clearing the browser cache, loads up my homepage. When i try routing to another url like 127.0.0.1:8000/login , I get a 500 error in Chrome... This page isn’t working 127.0.0.1 is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: Then it means there is issue with your code. Check laravel.log file then